# Trying to install pymgclient with poetry package manager

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I tried to install pymgclient with poetry package manager. However, when installing pymgclient, I get the subsequent error:

```
   x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DMGCLIENT_STATIC_DEFINE= -I/tmp/pip-req-build-mkeehpn7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/mgclient_install/include -I/home/josip/Memgraph-Repos/feature-not-bug/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/column.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/column.o

In file included from src/column.c:15:
src/column.h:18:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
18 | #include <Python.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I suppose the problem is somehow linked to the python3 version I suppose, I currently have python version 3.9.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pymgclient` requires `python-dev package` to be installed (on Ubuntu/Debian). To make this work, please run (on Ubuntu/Debian):
• `sudo apt install python-devor`
• `sudo apt install python3.9-dev` (in case a specific python version is used)
All the details could be found here [Introduction — pymgclient 1.0.0 documentation](https://memgraph.github.io/pymgclient/introduction.html#build-prerequisites)